# How to add custom domain from rails application to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, subdomain

I'm creating a rails app, which dynamically generates a content which depends on country which we get from subdomain. For example, user on the main page - **test.com**, then he select country Egypt for example, and he redirects to **egypt.test.com**. The list of countries we get from admin panel (only admin can create a country).I need to add this country subdomain when admin create it. I know the command:

```
heroku domains:add country.test.com
```

I guess, I need to put it on the rake task?? So, when admin creates a country in automatically run the rake task which adds the country subdomain, but I don't know how to write it? Can someone explain it to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using Heroku's Platform API, you can [assign domains to an app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#domain-create) programmatically.

So in the case of your example, the following curl command will add the domain to the app:

```
curl -n -X POST https://api.heroku.com/apps/$APP_ID_OR_NAME/domains \
  -d '{"hostname": "country.test.com"}' \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Can I use this curl command from the rails rake task? Is it possible?

Comment: You can, but using an actual ruby HTTP library would be much more efficient.

Comment: This gem will also allow you to do this more easily: https://github.com/heroku/platform-api